# understanding gitignore with subdirs

Tags: git, gitignore

If I have the following directory layout:

```
/
 - a
   - b
     - c.txt
```

and the following `.gitignore`

```
b/
```

it will match (i.e. ignore) the file, but if the `.gitignore` is

```
b/*
```

it won't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct.  Directory separators at the end of a path don't cause it to be anchored to a particular location, but directory separators at the beginning or in the middle will cause it to be anchored to the directory in which the `.gitignore` file is located.

From `gitignore(5)`:

> If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular .gitignore file itself.  Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the .gitignore level.